# Getting hexadecimal value 0x3c is an invalid attribute character

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I have a string like this:

```
String xmlStr = "<Tag attribute1=\"some text goes here &lt;textInBrackets&gt;\" attribute2=\"other text\"></Tag>";
```

Trying to load xml using:

```
XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
xd.LoadXML(xmlStr);
```

Code breaks at loadXml with error "hexadecimal value 0x3c is an invalid attribute character". Read few articles - it is mentioned that reserved char should be escaped - which it is. Not sure what m I missing here.
I need to escape the < and > chars here - <textInBrackets> Can not remove the brackets. Thoughts?

Comment: See wiki.  It is the ampersand: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references?force_isolation=true

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUKgBgAJVMA6ADQFsAbAbjz1QGYT0iBhIgbzyP7bteuAaJKZiAD1oBlYGCIBeIgCIAPABUAhgHMiW4PICWAIwjAAppkUAdFQGcA9lQtFLk4ER2OL9ogAsLMFcAMhpgOndgAEkoACEwLQBjAGsLYHsQnQi7fUMwU3MLdFsVR2BAhSi7AD41AHptHRqVBhExfgA3LQU4JSIoCwB3ImoaABFHJIgXKGAACgBKNo7+ODIAGUctODH56Ro5MGW+VdIATnn1gHkisDGT9v4AXzxnoA=).